# error implementation callback in nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

this is my code

```
Event.find({ start_date: { $lte: new Date() }, end_date: { $gte: new Date() }, isDeleted: false }).limit(10).sort({ created_at: 'desc' }).populate('moderator').exec(function (err, events) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var response = [];
    events.forEach(function (ev) {

        var moderatorName = ev.moderator.facebook.name;

        User.find({ currentEvent: ev._id }).exec(function (err, users) {

            callback(null, users);
        });


        if (ev.isFanPage)
            moderatorName = ev.fanPageName;

        response.push({ eventId: ev._id, title: ev.name, description: ev.description, thumb: ev.thumb, moderator: moderatorName, moderatorFbId: ev.moderator.facebook.id, countPicture: ev.numberOfUploadedImages, countVideo: users });
    });

    next(response);
});
```

I want to insert the list of users of the event in field contvideo the my response.

I used bad callback ?

**UPDATE 16/03/2016**

My solution is call function callback in function the find user the event.

my function find user the event.

```
exports.getEventUsers = function (id, next, callback) {
console.log("id evento " + id);
User.find({ currentEvent: id }).exec(function (err, users) {
    if (err)
        res.send("ERROR");

   callback(users);


});};
```

my proces event is

```
Event.find({ isDeleted: false }).limit(10).sort({ created_at: 'desc' }).populate('moderator').exec(function (err, events) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var response = [];
    var namearray = [];
    var total = events.length;
    console.log("cant evento" + total);
    events.forEach(function (ev) {

        var moderatorName = ev.moderator.facebook.name;
        var usuario = [];
        if (ev.isFanPage)
            moderatorName = ev.fanPageName;

        console.log("evento id " + ev._id);

        exports.getEventUsers(ev._id,next,function(retorno) {
            total--;
            console.log("evento id " + ev._id);
            console.log("cantidad elementos evento " + response.length);
            response.push({ eventId: ev._id, title: ev.name, description: ev.description, thumb: ev.thumb, moderator: moderatorName, moderatorFbId: ev.moderator.facebook.id, countPicture: ev.numberOfUploadedImages, participantes: retorno.length });

            if(total == 0)
            next(response);

        });

    });

    console.log("termino el proceso");
});
```

Comment: You can use `next(err)` in case of error and handle it after all routes in middleware.

Answer (score 0):

You can put errors in `next` handle and let it handle by error middleware.

```
Event.find({ start_date: { $lte: new Date() }, end_date: { $gte: new Date() }, isDeleted: false }).limit(10).sort({ created_at: 'desc' }).populate('moderator').exec(function (err, events) {
    if (err) 
        next(err);

    var response = [];
    events.forEach(function (ev) {
       var moderatorName = ev.moderator.facebook.name;

       User.find({ currentEvent: ev._id }).exec(function (err, users) {
            if err
               next(err);
            // DO whatever you want to with users
       });

       if (ev.isFanPage)
          moderatorName = ev.fanPageName;

       response.push({ eventId: ev._id, title: ev.name, description: ev.description, thumb: ev.thumb, moderator: moderatorName, moderatorFbId: ev.moderator.facebook.id, countPicture: ev.numberOfUploadedImages, countVideo: users });
    });
    next(response);
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
   //handle the errors here.
   console.log(err);
   res.send(err);
});
```

Comment: thanks, but the error is that "users" is not defined in the following statement. response.push({ ............ countVideo: users });

Comment: yes, it would raise the error, I commented that line. Its boilerplate code for the approach you wanted. If you want user object, then you can put `response.push` inside `User.find` .

Comment: yes, i can put response.push inside (user.find) but my response include only event with user. I need all events with users or not. you have one example the code for my problema ?